# Не работает пагинация на странице

Tags: php, wordpress, url, pagination

Есть архив news, странице даю такой же slug и не работает пагинация. Как это пофиксить, чтобы не менять название архива и слаг страницы остался news?

При переходе на старницу кидает на 404ую но у 404ой урла site/news/page/2, то есть такая как должна быть у пагинации. Если делаю в cpt has_archive => true, то редиректит на главную. Вообще не понимаю как исправить

Comment: Если меняю слаг страницы то все работает. Возможно ли вообще сделать так чтоб arhive был таким же как slug страницы? Мне нужно чтоб урла поста была site/news/post_slug а урл страницы был site/news. Или лучше переделать по archive а не через страницу выводить?

Comment: Так делать нельзя,  чтобы слаги были одинаковые. Забудьте эту тему.

Comment: Я догадывался). Провозился с этим долго, но решили просто назвать страницу our-news и сделать редиректы